# ActiveDirectory Object's list of allowed attributes

Tags: active-directory

I would like to know if it's possible to query ActiveDirectory for list of attributes that a directory entry has by supplying directory entry's schemaClass string only. 
As an example I have a string = "user" and would like to query AD for list of attributes that can be read/set for object that has it's SchemaClassName set to "user".
Hope it makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, with AD it is not that simple.
The best method to start on this quest is [Determining the Classes Associated With an Object Instance (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

AD defines Auxiliary Classes by:
[Statically Linked Auxiliary Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) 
and
[Dynamically Linked Auxiliary Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

-jim